# #define a variable value? preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm wondering if is it possible somehow to make something like this in C/C++:

```
int a = 5;
#define A a
printf("%s\n", A); // should print 5 (value of 'a' variable)
```

Ok, this code gives me segmentation fault (Windows 7, Code::Blocks):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    #define A a

    #if defined(A)
        printf("%d\n", A);
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In order for your question to be presentable, it should say what doesn't work. If your problem is this code not working, it should be cut down. Notice `printf("%s\n", 5);` probably does the same thing.

Comment: Why `%s`, not `%d`? [With `%d` it's going to just work](http://ideone.com/6QkSkt).

Comment: If you would have tried to compile what you have written it, you would have your answer(also replace %s with %d).

Comment: But this is a typical XY problem, or not? Why would s.o. want to use define for this. Baaaaaad design, whatever concerns!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain coding styles could save you from many errors including the one above.
In real world applications you **WONT** know what the macro will be so it will be hard to choose between ***%s*** and ***%d***.

*Sometimes it's not the issues, it's the beliefs leading to them.*

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Examples:

This is a bad coding-style:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    #define A a

    #if defined(A)
        printf("%d\n", A);
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

This is a tolerable* coding-style

```
int main()
{
    #ifdef WIN32
        #define a 5
    #elif defined __unix__
        #define a 6
    #endif

    int A = a;

    printf("%d\n",A);

    return 0;
}
```

- Depends on the coding *policy* of your team.

This is the preferred coding style:

```
int main()
{
    int A = 6;

    #ifdef WIN32
        A = 5;  // Windows hate 6 and *nix.
    #endif

    printf("%d\n",A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _'This is a tolerable coding-style'_ Arguable!

Comment: @g-makulik It depends on the *policy* of your team. My team prefers to use as less macros as possible.

Comment: Righteous guys you are ;). I'd always try to abstract such things (like OS dependent implementations) out using either dynamic or static polymorphism techniques.

Comment: @g-makulik You're right, even though when you have to deal with cross-platform-compatibility-temptations it's almost impossible to avoid them.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `%d` instead of `%s`:

```
printf("%d\n", A);
```

Check [this](http://ideone.com/uBxpAQ) out, it works!